# Is there any way I can get Google Music to ignore certain folders when scanning for music to upload?

Tags: windows-7, google-music

I have my music organised under a single "music" folder, but that contains some music files that I don't want to upload to Google Music. When you select a folder to upload you just get that folder name displayed, there's no tree view of all the folders underneath that root.

I know I could move these folders elsewhere on my hard drive, but that would break my local workflow for managing these tracks.

So what I'm looking for is a way to mark certain folders as either invisible to Google Music, or ignored by Google Music.

Comment: What's your OS? Would it be possible (and practical) to create a tree of symlinks with your desired directories?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida - Windows. (I forgot to add the tag)

Comment: @PauloAlmeida - that seems like a lot of effort - I might as well reorganise my music on the disk.

Comment: What about running the Google music updater as another user and then revoke that users read access for certain directories?

Comment: Can you add a file called `.nomedia` in to the directories you don't want to sync?